# Filebeat | can't pass logs from two differenet paths

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, containers, filebeat

I am trying to configure the filebeat agent on the k8s cluster to ship all the logs to elastic from two different paths:

1. /var/logs/containers/*.log
2. /var/logs/agents/*.log

I tried writing the config files but the logs are passing only from /var/logs/containers/*.log

this is the full config file:

```
   filebeat.autodiscover:
     providers:
      - type: kubernetes
        hints.enabled: true
        hints.default_config:
          enabled: false
          type: container
          paths:
            - /var/log/containers/*.log  # CRI path
            - /var/log/agents/*.log

  output.elasticsearch:
    protocol: http
    hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    compression_level: 1
    indices:
    - index: "agent-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "agents"
    - index: "container-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "containers"
```

and I also tried this config, but when I run this config I only get agent logs:

```
  filebeat.autodiscover:
    providers:
      - type: kubernetes
        hints.enabled: true
        hints.default_config:
          enabled: false
          type: container
          paths:
            - /var/log/containers/*.log
  filebeat.inputs:
   - type: filestream
     id: agent-filestream
     paths:
      - "/var/log/agents/*.log"

  output.elasticsearch:
    protocol: http
    hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    compression_level: 1
    indices:
    - index: "container-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "containers"
    - index: "agent-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "agents"
```

please help!
thank you

Comment: your second code will probably work if you change "enabled: false"  to "enabled: true".
the first one does not work because I think "/var/log/agents/*.log" is not kubernetes logs.

Comment: Hi @EisaQasemi thank you for your response. The solution you gave me only collects logs from /var/log/containers and not from both paths... what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it eventually,
that is the right config file:

```
  filebeat.autodiscover:
    providers:
      - type: kubernetes
        hints.enabled: true
        hints.default_config:
          enabled: false
          type: container
          paths:
            - /var/log/containers/*.log
  filebeat.inputs:
    - type: log
      enabled: true
      paths:
        - /var/log/agents/*.log   
        
  output.elasticsearch:
    protocol: http
    hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    compression_level: 1
    indices:
    - index: "container-logs"
      when:
        contains:
          log.file.path: "containers"
    - index: "agent-logs"
      when:
        contains:
          log.file.path: "agents"
```